# Entity Framework 6.2 - Migration Is Adding Properties of Derived Table Model to Inherited Table Model

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Let's illustrate...

```
public class Base
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class B : A
{
    public string Whatever { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have a setup similar to above. When adding a migration to update the database with the table for **model B**, it generates code that will update the table for **model A** with the properties of **model B** - the opposite of what should be happening!

So, in this example, the table for **model A** will be given a *Whatever* column, and a table for **model B** is not created.

I've never come across this behaviour before. Why would this be happening?

Thanks

**EDIT:** My DbContext class has a *DbSet* for both **model A** and **model B**, respectfully (and they're both public properties).

Comment: This  concept is called TPH - Table per Hierarchy, when EF will store all your class hierarchy in one table. The 'discriminator' column is used to distinguish what type is the record. You can specify to use other approach, for example, Table per Type or Table per Class, it must be configured using fluent API or annotations. Check out this [multi part article](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

Answer (score 0):

The comment from Ivvan is the answer: Table Per Hierarchy (TPH) was happening.

I refer any reader to the article Ivvan linked for further information on how this works: [EF Code First - Part 1 - TPH](https://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph)

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21633331)

Comment: @AndreyNikolov ...but wouldn't a "complete" answer, in this case, include a full description and discussion on how Table Per Hierarchy works? The post I (and Ivvan) linked to gives the complete overview and details. I wouldn't want to repeat it :) I posted this as the answer so that anyone seeing this in the future can quickly navigate to it. Plus, Ivvan's comment is really the answer, so I wanted to highlight this. Please define what a "complete answer" is, and I'll certainly amend it to this satisfaction.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) explains that.